# How are weights saved in the CIFAR10 tutorial for tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

In the TensorFlow tutorial to train a network on CIFAR-10, where and how do they save the weights/parameters between running training and evaluation? I cannot see any files saved to my project directory.

Here are the links to the tutorial and the code:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It saves the logs and checkpoints to the `/tmp/` folder by default.
The weights are included in the checkpoint files.

As you can see in both eval and train files, it does take a checkpoint dir as parameter.

cifar10_train.py:

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('train_dir', '/tmp/cifar10_train',
                           """Directory where to write event logs """
                           """and checkpoint.""")
```

cifar10_eval.py:

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('eval_dir', '/tmp/cifar10_eval',
                           """Directory where to write event logs.""")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('eval_data', 'test',
                           """Either 'test' or 'train_eval'.""")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('checkpoint_dir', '/tmp/cifar10_train',
                           """Directory where to read model checkpoints.""")
```

You can call those scripts with custom values for those. For my project using Inception I have to change it since the main hard drive does not have enough space for the bottlenecks created by inception.

It might be a good practice to explicitly set those values since the `/tmp/` folder is not persistent and thus you might lose your training data.

The following code will save the training data into a custom folder.

```
python cifar10_train.py --train_dir="/home/username/train_folder"
```

and then, to evaluate:

```
python cifar10_eval.py --checkpoint_dir="/home/username/train_folder"
```

It also applies to the other examples.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you're running cifar10_train, saving happens on this line:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py#L122

And the default location is defined in this line (it's "/tmp/cifar10_train"):

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py#L51

In cifar10_eval, restoring the weights happens on this line:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py#L75

Comment: Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.